# make lottie animation setVisibility immediately

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-animation, lottie

i have an adroid project and i want to show a lottie animation during the time that an algorithm run but it does not become visible at time.

in my xml file:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/loading" />
```

// i tried also with  android:visibility="invisible"

in java:

```
LottieAnimationView lottieanimationview;
lottieanimationview = findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
```

in specific function where i want to start to see the animation, i write:

```
lottieanimationview.setVisibility(LottieAnimationView.VISIBLE);
```

then, inside this function i have a call to another function that run the algorithm (in a cpp file that in the project).

now, instead of get visible and then run the another function (i want it to be like a loading animation),
the lottie get visible just *after* the run of the second function done. how can i make the lottie get visible immediately when i call setVisibility?
thank you

Comment: try lottieanimationview.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @AkashBisht I tried, but still the lottie showed up just at the end of the function's run.

Comment: You can try wrapping lotto animation view inside a layout, for example linear layout, and then try to set visibilty of layout.

Comment: @AkashBisht i'm new in android studio, can ypu please expand how exactly should i do it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. Here is the code which I tried :

I have some lottie views in this(Screenshot attached below).
But we will be only using toggle view and thumbsDown
When we switch Toggle on, we are setting thumbsdown view visibilty gone
and when we switch Toggle off, thumbsdown view is visible again.

activity_main.xml

> ```
> <!-- Custom Action Bar -->
> <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
>     android:id="@+id/lav_actionBar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="75dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
>     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
>     app:lottie_fileName="gradient_bg.json"
>     app:lottie_loop="true" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>     android:text="Demo Lottie"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:textSize="30sp"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/lav_actionBar"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/lav_actionBar"
>     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lav_actionBar" />
>
> <!-- Thumbs Up Button -->
> <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
>     android:id="@+id/lav_thumbUp"
>     android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
>     app:lottie_fileName="thumb_up.json"
>     app:lottie_loop="false"
>     app:lottie_speed="1.25" />
>
> <!-- Thumbs Down Button (We just rotate the previous one by 180 deg ;) )-->
> <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
>     android:id="@+id/lav_thumbDown"
>     android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>     android:rotation="180"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
>     app:lottie_fileName="thumb_up.json"
>     app:lottie_loop="false"
>     app:lottie_speed="1.25" />
>
> <!-- Toggle Switch -->
> <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
>     android:id="@+id/lav_toggle"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lav_thumbUp"
>     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
>     app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
>     app:lottie_fileName="toggle_switch.json"
>     app:lottie_loop="false"
>     app:lottie_speed="1.75" />
> ```
>
> [image]

MainActivity.java

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> LottieAnimationView thumb_up;
> LottieAnimationView thumb_down;
> LottieAnimationView toggle;
> LottieAnimationView imprint;
> int flag = 0;
>
>
> @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     thumb_up = findViewById(R.id.lav_thumbUp);
>     thumb_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             thumb_down.setProgress(0);
>             thumb_down.pauseAnimation();
>             thumb_up.playAnimation();
>             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cheers!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             //---- Your code here------
>         }
>     });
>
>     thumb_down = findViewById(R.id.lav_thumbDown);
>     thumb_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             thumb_up.setProgress(0);
>             thumb_up.pauseAnimation();
>             thumb_down.playAnimation();
>             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boo!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             //---- Your code here------
>         }
>     });
>
>     toggle = findViewById(R.id.lav_toggle);
>     toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             changeState();
>         }
>     });
> } //
> private void changeState() {
>     if (flag == 0) {
>         toggle.setMinAndMaxProgress(0f, 0.43f);
>         toggle.playAnimation();
>         flag = 1;
>         //---- Your code here------
>         thumb_down.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>     } else {
>         toggle.setMinAndMaxProgress(0.5f, 1f);
>         toggle.playAnimation();
>         flag = 0;
>         //---- Your code here------
>         thumb_down.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     }
> } }
> ```

[image]

Main thing is :

```
thumb_down.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
thumb_down.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope it helps.